# virtual hosts aren't resolving correctly

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have the following vhosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/mycheck.il"
    ServerName mobile.mycheck
    ErrorLog "logs/mobile.mycheck.log"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/api.il"
    ServerName api.mycheck
    ErrorLog "logs/api.mycheck.log"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/admin"
    ServerName front.mycheck
    ErrorLog "logs/front.mycheck.log"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

and using windows, I have the following hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mobile.mycheck
127.0.0.1       api.mycheck
127.0.0.1       front.mycheck
```

However, no matter what vhost I try to put in my browser, I always resolve to the same directory `(projects/mycheck.il)`, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line before your VirtualHost declarations:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```